# Confusion in Notation

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrinos

Recently I am doing a project on KATRIN experiment, which motive is to find the neutrino mass. So in a paper the result shows $(m_\nu)^2 =(-1.0)^{+0.9}_{-1.1}$   $eV^2 $. I do not get the meaning of writing numbers in super and subscripts. Does it specify some kind of error?

Comment: Duplicate [Asymmetric uncertainties](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61228/asymmetric-uncertainties)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it means that the experimental uncertainty is asymmetric.  In elementary contexts, one often writes uncertainties in the form $\overline x \pm \delta $, but this implies that the true value is just as likely to be $\overline x+\delta $ as it is to be $\overline x-\delta $.  In other words, the probability distribution associated to the measurement is symmetric about $\overline x$.

In more careful treatments, one often finds this *not* to be true, and that a more accurate description of the experimental uncertainty would capture the fact that the uncertainty is greater in one direction than the other. To reflect this, one writes $\big(\overline x\big)^{+\delta_1}_{-\delta_2}$.

For more information, you may find [this PSE Q&A](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61228/asymmetric-uncertainties) useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped